# Estoy tratando de importar app en android studio y me marca este error

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando importar una aplicación en Android Studio para poder abrir el proyecto y seguir con su desarrollo pero me marca el error de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi version del SDK Tools es a 25.2.3 como se puede ver en la siguiente captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tienes  Android SDK Tools 25.0.0  instalado?

Comment: el 7.1.1 api 25 ? seguro? 
Borra tu propia respuesta que has escrito abajo, por favor

Comment: Buenas algo parecido pasa con Tomcat si tienes una version mas avanzada que la JDK te permite. ¿Que versión de java tienes instalada? La minima version que deberias tener es la 1.7 Saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Android Studio tienes ?, Por favor no añadas más cosas a la respuesta de abajo, añádelas en este mismo hilo. ok ya  la veo la 2.1.2

Comment: Aquí tienes unas cuantas soluciones:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466744/android-studio-continues-to-get-a-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: Como te han comentado las respuestas son solo para respuestas, si necesitas añadir información a la pregunta usa el botón `editar` que hay debajo de ella. He editado la pregunta añadiendo la informacíon de tu respuesta que sera eliminada posiblemente.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes actualizado build tools y tu sdk, entonces simplemente actualiza la versión de gradle, dentro del archivo `build.gradle` del proyecto (a la última versión):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'              
    }
}
```